# Converting to list comprehension with mutable obj

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For the following:

```
data = []
for item in self.matches:
    for k,v in item.items():
        if isinstance(v, Decimal):
            item[k]=float(v)
    data.append(item)
```

Is it possible to convert the above into a list comprehension (mainly due to the mutability of item)? If so, how could this be done?

Comment: Please don't. It'd be a nested comprehension... for what? If you're not comfortable in building it in the first place, why do you feel it should be in your code?

Comment: @roganjosh more just to see if it's possible to do so with a mutable object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not advisable, but if you really wanted, it would be:

```py
data = [{k:float(v) if isinstance(v, Decimal) else v for k,v in item.items()} for item in self.matches]
```

You got stuck because it seems like you modify the object and not just appending it. The trick is to create a new dict with the condition.

But, not anything should be converted to a list-comprehension. As you can see this is must less readable than a standard loop.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and I appreciate your advice on the readability and all.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function to perform the inner loop, then call that in the list comprehension.

```
def decimal_to_float(item):
    for k, v in item.items():
        if isinstance(v, Decimal):
            item[k]=float(v)
    return item

data = [decimal_to_float(item) for item in self.matches]
```